# Django--How to Represent 2 Way Following Relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I want users to be able to follow each other (each user can follow and be followed by multiple users).  Is there anything wrong with representing it with ForeignKeys?

```
    class Follow(models.Model):
      followed=models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
      follower=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="follower")

      def __unicode__(self):
           return self.followed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off using a ManyToMany with self on a `Person` or `User` class. For example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=50)
    followers = ManyToMany("self", related_name="following")
```

This way, with much less code, you can do things like:

```
p = Person.objects.get(first_name="bob")
p.following.all() # Everyone bob is following
p.followers.all() # Everyone that is following bob
```

See the Django docs for more information on ManyToMany with self.

Comment: I don't undestand one thing here.  Is the M2M relationship symmetrical, meaning whoever follow a person is also followed by that person and vice versa? If that's not the case, I don't understand how this is working.  If that IS the case, I want slightly different functionality (the relationship shouldn't be symmetrical)

Comment: The relation here won't be symmetrical. You'll have to add it manually both way for it to be symmetrical.